# Create alpine linux iso from docker - libburn permission denied

Tags: docker, iso, alpine-linux

I have been trying to build an iso-image for alpine-linux inside a docker container following the standard instructions [here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/How_to_make_a_custom_ISO_image) however i seem to be unable to actually write the .iso back into the mounted volume due to libburn :

```
    >>> mkimage-x86_64: Creating alpine-standard-edge-x86_64.iso
xorriso 1.4.8 : RockRidge filesystem manipulator, libburnia project.

libburn : SORRY : Failed to open device (a pseudo-drive) : Permission denied
libburn : FATAL : Burn run failed
xorriso : FATAL : -abort_on 'FAILURE' encountered 'FATAL' during image writing
libisofs: MISHAP : Image write cancelled
xorriso : FAILURE : libburn indicates failure with writing.
```

This is the standard result of trying to run the downloaded script from the tutorial:

```
sh aports/scripts/mkimage.sh --tag edge --outdir /build2/ --arch x86_64 --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main --profile standard
```

The docker image im using:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN addgroup root abuild
RUN apk add --update \
    alpine-sdk \
   # build-base \
    apk-tools \
    alpine-conf \
    busybox \
    git \
    fakeroot \
    syslinux \
    xorriso \
    squashfs-tools \
    mtools \
    dosfstools \
    grub-efi \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY . /usr/src/app 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app/build
RUN touch /usr/src/app/build/worked.txt
RUN adduser -G abuild -g "Alpine Package Builder" -s /bin/sh -u 12345 -D builder
RUN echo "builder:newpass"|chpasswd


RUN chgrp -R abuild /usr/local;                                      \
    find /usr/local -type d | xargs chmod g+w;                        \
    echo "builder ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers.d/builder; \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/builder

WORKDIR /build2/
RUN git clone git://git.alpinelinux.org/aports
RUN chmod +x aports/scripts/mkimage.sh
RUN abuild-keygen -i -a
USER builder
```

I have looked over the official forum however only one post mentioned something similar but did not allude to any actual resolution.

Failing to find a solution for this, can anyone else recommend a good alternative minimal distro that can be build an iso via script for x_86, x_64 and rpi?

Comment: The "device (a pseudo-drive)" is your resulting ISO,
alpine-standard-edge-x86_64.iso . So i expect that you do not have
permission to open that file (for truncation) or to create it.
Check whether it already exists and the permissions of the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily create your own Alpine Linux ISO image using script [alpine-make-vm-image](https://github.com/alpinelinux/alpine-make-vm-image).

Example:

```sh
sudo ./alpine-make-vm-image \
  --image-format qcow2 \
  --image-size 5G \
  --packages "ca-certificates git ssl_client" \
  --script-chroot \
  alpine-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).qcow2 -- ./configure.sh
```

Comment: does this work inside a container is the main issue im having, i want to deploy a script inside a container to generate an iso image into a mounted volume, the suggested way from the alpine website didnt work as i said in my original statement but i will give your suggestion a try inside docker and see

Comment: It depends on your setup; you need privileges to do a chroot, then it will work ofc.

Comment: The page on the Alpine wiki started with a warning that it’s obsolete… I’ve already replaced it with a link to alpine-make-vm-image.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a permission denied error because the user you created can't access the pseudo device needed by xorriso.  I removed all the user creation parts and just ran the whole thing as root and it works.

Here's the Dockerfile I used:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    alpine-conf \
    alpine-sdk \
    apk-tools \
    dosfstools \
    grub-efi \
    mtools \
    squashfs-tools \
    syslinux \
    xorriso

WORKDIR /src

RUN git clone git://git.alpinelinux.org/aports

RUN chmod +x aports/scripts/mkimage.sh

RUN addgroup root abuild

RUN abuild-keygen -i -a -n

WORKDIR /build

ENTRYPOINT /src/aports/scripts/mkimage.sh

CMD "--tag edge --arch x86_64 --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main --profile standard"
```

Then build and run.

`docker build -t alpine-iso .`

`docker run -v "$(pwd):/build" -it alpine-iso`